# What is the fastest way to check an internet connection using C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, internet-connection

I'm trying to write a program in C/C++ to check the internet connection on a windows machine. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Fastest in what sense? To develop? Number of cpu cycle? Amount of network traffic required?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work on a Windows machine using Visual Studio. By fastest, I mean the best and most efficient way in a programmer sense. Easy to program and works.

Comment: Fork a ping and capture the result.

Comment: @TZHX _Fork_? Are you serious? On what planet will that be the "fastest way"?

Comment: @stefan what do you mean by fastest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only show you a short way, based on a microsoft example. In fact, the only way to make sure you can connect to the internet is to try to connect to a server in the internet. Most applications use google as target-server or their own server (if they have one). I modified the example to connect to google on port 80. If the program return 0, it was a success, otherwise it returns 1. This should give you are startpoint to an own solution:

```
// example from:
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "80"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;


    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("www.google.com", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
/*  do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );
*/
    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

if you change the buffer from "this is a test" to a valid http request, you can even get an response you can read (I comment that part away). This is not necessary as a connect with TCP/IP already says that a connection is possible. There are of course UDP ping ways, but they have (in my opinion) no advantage. The name resolving can be dropped and you can use an ip directly. Name resolving is no sign of a working internet as most provider have internal DNS server which can be up even if the connection to the internet is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen people use the `InternetCheckConnection` function, [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).